# Windows: remote desktop into a virtual desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, remote-desktop, virtual-desktop

Windows 10 finally [added virtual desktops as a built-in feature](https://www.howtogeek.com/197625/how-to-use-virtual-desktops-in-windows-10/).

Would Windows 10 remote desktop tool be able to RDP into a designated virtual desktop?

The reason I'm asking is that if I ever do remote desktop from home to my office, it will always screws up my Windows desktop layout in my office, because at my company I have due display but at home I only have single monitor.

The next day I get back into my office, all windows, which were arranged nicely on my due display, are squeezed into one display, and a smaller viewing area, as my home laptop has much smaller resolution.

RDP into another virtual desktop solve the above problem nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I frequently remote in to them with rdp. just assign a static address to them and enable RDP. You have to use the hyper-visor to set this up, but once you do it is s a lot easier to manage them with RDP.

Comment: I believe you are talking a different thing than mine. Here is a quote from my above linked article: _"With virtual desktops, Windows 10 lets you create multiple, separate desktops that each can display different open windows and apps. A simple use for this might be keeping work separate from personal stuff. You could also put all the items that relate to a specific task on one desktop, so that you can better focus on that task. While macOS and Linux have featured virtual desktops for a while, virtual desktops are now built into Windows 10."_